# Restrict editing access to my PostgreSQL/ PostGIS database used through QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

We have a small network of users accessing our QGIS data stored on a PostGIS database which sits on a 'Q' drive in my computer. This drive is then shared with the others.
Due to the other users being beginners in the GIS world I created a number of layer files (.qlr) for them which point back to the data in my PostGIS database. They can only see these layer files.

But I've just realised when they use these layer files they can still edit, add and remove the data.

How do I restrict this?

Is there a simple way in QGIS or even Windows? (setting permissions on the sharing folders does not seem to work)

The database was created through something called 'pgAdmin 4' and I've tried adding another user/role with different privileges but I can't seem to get that to work its seems to deny access completely or its all still wide open.

The privileges I can alter seem to be too high up the hierarchy all I need to restrict is the ability to write and delete to the schema's and tables, leaving myself with editing rights.

I have no idea how to write in SQL, I'm a geographer not IT

Comment: you need your users to login a with a different role (that is restricted) we do this for over 300 users.

Comment: Groups and Roles GRANT and REVOKE http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-roles/

Comment: This isn't a GIS question so much as a Intro to Relational Database Security Models question (ripe for [dba.se]).  You have described a severely dysfunctional security configuration. *Someone* needs to step up and impose order, or your organization might lose all the data in the database through neglect. It's important to understand that the PostgreSQL data is not shared via the Q drive, but by the PG table reference stored in the layer files.

Comment: As both PostgreSQL and PostGIS are free you could set up some sort of one-way replication as a stopgap, users that edit connect to 'x', users that don't connect to 'y' with 'x' overwriting 'y' on a regular basis.. both Vince and Mappers are right, you've got a dysfunctional system that probably started from a test bed and has grown into a monster now you need to consider creating group roles 1 with SELECT only and the other with SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE then assign users login roles to groups. I found PGAdmin 3 easier to use than the newer version.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, the issues is there is no database administrator and no organisation, there is just me a GIS analyst. I'm volunteering in a developing country and we cobbled this thing together months ago by luck just by following the steps on the Pgadmin help pages. I will try the Database Administrators but I doubt I will understand the answers from them